# Upgrading from ubuntu 11.04 to the latest version

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to fix an old laptop. The CD-ROM drive can only read CDs and I have only Ubuntu server 11.04 on a CD. I wasn't able to boot from USB.

So I installed Ubuntu server 11.04 on the machine and now i'm trying to make it up-to-date with the latest version of ubuntu. However, when I write `do-release-upgrade` I get that there is no new release!

I couldn't find `ubuntu-desktop` when I tried to install it with `apt-get`. Any solutions please?

Comment: Why not install a supported version?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to update manually you have to upgrade from 11.04 to 11.10 to 12.04 to 14.04, so it's easier to download a DVD image of the latest stable Ubuntu version and burn it and boot that...

If you would insist going to the latest (but least stable) version of Ubuntu, you have to additionally upgrade to 14.10 to 15.04 - there you go...

Comment: Why not install a 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Of course that would be the right solution - but he asked for an upgrade - so this would have been the upgrade path...